# How can I avoid the infinite loop in useEffect?

Tags: reactjs

I need your help. I'm creating an app with useContext and useReducer hooks and I a have problems. I have a function to get all notes from my database. I called that function inside off useEffect hook:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
//Context
import AuthContext from "../../context/auth/authContext";
import NoteContext from '../../context/notes/noteContext';
//Components
import { Row, Col, Container, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import Canva from '../Canva/Canva';
import Note from '../Note/Note';

const Dashboard = () => {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { authUser, user } = authContext;
  const noteContext = useContext(NoteContext);
  const { notes, getNotes, addNote } = noteContext;
  useEffect(() => {
    getNotes();
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col sm={12} md={10}>
            <Button onClick={() => addNote()} type='button' className='mb-2'>
              Añadir elemento
            </Button>
            <Canva>
              {notes && (notes.map(note => {
                return (
                  <Note key={note._id} note={note} />
                )
              }))}
            </Canva>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

If I called that function that way, my state doesn't change:

```
notes: undefined
```

But if I introduce a dependency inside of useEffect, my app goes into an infinite loop. For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getNotes();
}, [notes])

//Or:
useEffect(() => {
  getNotes()
}, [getNotes])
```

How can I avoid the infinite loop?

Comment: Show what's inside NoteContext

Comment: @IanVasco ready

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 2 useEffect hooks, one for fetch data and second to proceed it:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getNotes();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  if (notes && notes.length) {
    ....setState or what else
  }
}, [notes]);
```

Comment: Thanks for you help but it doesn't works because getNotes modified notes state

Answer (score 0):

My note state looks like:

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';
import clientAxios from '../../config/clientAxios';
import NoteContext from './noteContext';
import NoteReducer  from './noteReducer';
import {
  GET_NOTES,
  ADD_NOTE,
  DELETE_NOTE,
  UPDATE_NOTE,
} from '../../types';
const NoteState = ({ children }) => {
  const initialState = {
    notes: [],
    noteError: false,
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(NoteReducer, initialState);

  const getNotes = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await clientAxios.get('/user/Notes');
      dispatch({
        type: GET_NOTES,
        payload: response.data
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response);
    }
  }

  const addNote = async data => {
    try {
      const response = await clientAxios.post('/addNote', data);
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_NOTE,
        payload: response.data.data
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response);
    }
  }

  const updateNote = async (id, { title, description }) => {
    try {
      const response = await clientAxios.put(`updateNote/${id}`, { title, description });
      console.log(response.data);
      dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_NOTE,
        payload: response.data
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response)
    }
  }

  const deleteNote = async id => {
    try {
      await clientAxios.put(`/deleteNote/${id}`);
      dispatch({
        type: DELETE_NOTE,
        payload: id
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response);
    }
  }

  return(
    <NoteContext.Provider
      value={{
        notes: state.notes,
        noteError: state.noteError,
        getNotes,
        addNote,
        updateNote,
        deleteNote,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </NoteContext.Provider>
  );
}
 
export default NoteState;
```

and my reducer:

```
import {
  GET_NOTES,
  ADD_NOTE,
  DELETE_NOTE,
  UPDATE_NOTE,
} from '../../types';
export default (action, state) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case GET_NOTES:
      return {
        ...state,
        notes: action.payload
      }
    case ADD_NOTE:
      return {
        ...state,
        notes: [...state.notes, action.payload]
      }
    case UPDATE_NOTE:
      return {
        ...state,
        notes: state.notes.map(note => note._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : note)
      }
    case DELETE_NOTE:
      return {
        ...state,
        notes: state.notes.filter(note => note._id !== action.payload),
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```